# Running .bat file on cygwin CLI without the .bat extension

Tags: cygwin

I have been looking for a way to run dos batch files from the cygwin command line without having the enter the extension.

Would that be possible?

Currently, I have to enter the extension otherwise cygwin does not find the batch file.

Comment: Why do you want that? Anyway if your batch file is file.bat, try: 'cmd /C file'

Comment: As a work around you can add alias command='command.bat' in your shell .profile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found no other solution so I did what golimar said.
Here is a simple script that looks for `.bat` files in a specific directory and creates aliases.
For example if there is a file `git.bat` in `/some/path` there will be a alias `git` that points to it.
Add this to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` or whatever you're using:

```
for f in /some/path/*.bat; do alias `basename "${f%.bat}"`=$f; done
```

Answer (score 3):

another workaround is to use the bash internal function `command_not_found_handle()` like this:

```
command_not_found_handle() {
    echo "bash: $1: command_not_found_handle()"  >&2
    LOWERCASE_CMD=$(echo "$1" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')
    shift
    [ -f /cygdrive/c/CLIPrograms/${LOWERCASE_CMD}.bat ] && /cygdrive/c/CLIPrograms/${LOWERCASE_CMD}.bat "$@"
    return $?
```

Comment: This is pretty awesome! Several pointers about your bash code. If using a variable inside a function, make sure you define it as `local` (unless you have a reason to create a global var. In my opinion, it is good style to use lower case for variables and upper case for (pseudo-)constants, although tastes vary. You can use `${1,,}` to lowercase $1, no need for a temp var, subshell and pipe. In case the `.bat` file doesn't exist, you want to print the standard `"bash: $1: command not found"` and `return 127`.